# Multiple Line Graphs in Fragment causes application Crash. Android Studio using Example Code

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, mpandroidchart, linegraph

I'm using an example from [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) (The Activity I am using as a template is called: `ListViewMultiChartActivity` ) I'm making a part of an application where I use fragments to show two views with graphs. My problem is with one of the `fragments` where I would like a list view with multiple graphs.

I have adapted the code to be used by a fragment, and not just an activity.
When I run the application, it crashes immediately, but there are no errors in the code. The Android monitor says the following:  **Error message updated**

```
05-09 08:51:31.365 25543-25543/com.example.christianulrich.viewstat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.christianulrich.viewstat, PID: 25543
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Description com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart.getDescription()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.christianulrich.viewstat.listviewitems.LineChartItem.getView(LineChartItem.java:54)
                                                                                      at com.example.christianulrich.viewstat.ViewStatisticsExerciseFragment$ChartDataAdapter.getView(ViewStatisticsExerciseFragment.java:104)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2162)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-09 08:51:31.365 25543-25543/com.example.christianulrich.viewstat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The rest of the code of the fragment can be seen here. (Updated)

```
package com.example.christianulrich.viewstat;

Imports....


/**
 * Created by Christian Ulrich on 04-05-2017.
 */

public class ViewStatisticsExerciseFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "View Exercises";

private Button btnHome;
private Button btnFile;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_statictis_exercise_fragment, 
container, false);

    btnHome = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHome2);
    btnFile = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFile2);

    btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TESTING BUTTON CLICK 1", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    ArrayList<ChartItem> list = new ArrayList<ChartItem>();

    // 30 items
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        if(i % 3 == 0) {
            list.add(new LineChartItem(generateDataLine(i + 1), 
getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        } else if(i % 3 == 1) {
            list.add(new BarChartItem(generateDataBar(i + 1), 
getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        } else if(i % 3 == 2) {
            list.add(new PieChartItem(generateDataPie(i + 1), 
getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        }
    }

        ChartDataAdapter cda = new ChartDataAdapter( 
getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);
        lv.setAdapter(cda);

    return view;
}
    /** adapter that supports 3 different item types */
    private class ChartDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChartItem> {

        public ChartDataAdapter(Context context, List<ChartItem> objects) {
            super(context, 0, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
parent) {
            return getItem(position).getView(position, convertView, 
getContext());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // return the views type
            return getItem(position).getItemType();
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 3; // we have 3 different item-types
        }
    }


    /**
     * generates a random ChartData object with just one DataSet
     *
     * @return
     */

    private LineData generateDataLine(int cnt) {

    ArrayList<Entry> e1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        e1.add(new Entry(i, (int) (Math.random() * 65) + 40));
    }

    LineDataSet d1 = new LineDataSet(e1, "New DataSet " + cnt + ", (1)");
    d1.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    d1.setCircleRadius(4.5f);
    d1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
    d1.setDrawValues(false);

    ArrayList<Entry> e2 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        e2.add(new Entry(i, e1.get(i).getY() - 30));
    }

    LineDataSet d2 = new LineDataSet(e2, "New DataSet " + cnt + ", (2)");
    d2.setLineWidth(2.5f);
    d2.setCircleRadius(4.5f);
    d2.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
    d2.setColor(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[0]);
    d2.setCircleColor(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[0]);
    d2.setDrawValues(false);

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> sets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    sets.add(d1);
    sets.add(d2);

    LineData cd = new LineData(sets);
    return cd;
}

/**
 * generates a random ChartData object with just one DataSet
 *
 * @return
 */
private BarData generateDataBar(int cnt) {

    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        entries.add(new BarEntry(i, (int) (Math.random() * 70) + 30));
    }

    BarDataSet d = new BarDataSet(entries, "New DataSet " + cnt);
    d.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
    d.setHighLightAlpha(255);

    BarData cd = new BarData(d);
    cd.setBarWidth(0.9f);
    return cd;
}

/**
 * generates a random ChartData object with just one DataSet
 *
 * @return
 */
private PieData generateDataPie(int cnt) {

    ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        entries.add(new PieEntry((float) ((Math.random() * 70) + 30), 
"Quarter " + (i + 1)));
    }

    PieDataSet d = new PieDataSet(entries, "");

    // space between slices
    d.setSliceSpace(2f);
    d.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);

    PieData cd = new PieData(d);
    return cd;
    }
}
```

I hope that some of you can be able to make sense of this, I do have ChartItem and LineChartItem as separate Classes.

Thank you in advance
Regards Christian

@David
Here is the rest of the code

Fragment XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHome2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.015"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.895" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFile2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Generate File"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.893"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.996" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="490dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

A new file was added called: list_item_chart.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

My helper Classes, ChartItem:

```
    package com.example.christianulrich.viewstat.listviewitems;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;

    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData;

    /**
     * baseclass of the chart-listview items
     * @author philipp
     *
     */
    public abstract class ChartItem {

    protected static final int TYPE_BARCHART = 0;
    protected static final int TYPE_LINECHART = 1;
    protected static final int TYPE_PIECHART = 2;

    protected ChartData<?> mChartData;

    public ChartItem(ChartData<?> cd) {
        this.mChartData = cd;      
    }

    public abstract int getItemType();

    public abstract View getView(int position, View convertView, Context c);
    }
```

And the next LineChartItem

```
    package com.example.christianulrich.viewstat.listviewitems;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;

    import com.example.christianulrich.viewstat.R;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis.XAxisPosition;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData;
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;


    public class LineChartItem extends ChartItem {

    private Typeface mTf;

    public LineChartItem(ChartData<?> cd, Context c) {
        super(cd);

        mTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemType() {
        return TYPE_LINECHART;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, Context c) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(
                    R.layout.view_statictis_exercise_fragment, null);
            holder.chart = (LineChart) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // apply styling
        // holder.chart.setValueTypeface(mTf);
        holder.chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        holder.chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        XAxis xAxis = holder.chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);

        YAxis leftAxis = holder.chart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
        leftAxis.setLabelCount(5, false);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        YAxis rightAxis = holder.chart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
        rightAxis.setLabelCount(5, false);
        rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        // set data
        holder.chart.setData((LineData) mChartData);

        // do not forget to refresh the chart
        // holder.chart.invalidate();
        holder.chart.animateX(750);

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        LineChart chart;
    }
    }
```

**I also added an assets folder with some fonts that it requested before this. **

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

The problem is here:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Check the XML for your LineChart and specifically the `id`. It should be something like `"android:id=@+id/lineChart"` *not* `"android:id=@+id/listView1"`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it turned out that I lacked 1 XML file, i added a list_Item_linechart.xml. And corrected the R.id Tags. I still end up with a new error in Monitor:                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
             method 'com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Description com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart.getDescription()' on a null object reference

Comment: @ChristianUlrich I'm glad it helped! Nice first question since you isolated the specific piece of code that was causing the problem

Comment: @ChristianUlrich are you calling `findViewById` on the `LineChart` etc.? You'll need to do that as well

Comment: @ David Rawson From my fragment I call:         ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);      I renamed the R.id  to listView1  this calls the <ListView> in my Fragment XML.   In my LineChartItem  I call:             holder.chart = (LineChart) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chart);  the "chart" id is connected to the new XML file i added "list_Item_linechart." which contains a liniar layout with     <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart.

Comment: @Christian that sounds about right. Can you edit your question to include that code?

Comment: @ChristianUlrich I copied your classes into the IDE and I couldn't reproduce your error. Please check that you are using unique ids for your views "chart" and "listView1" are a bit general and if you are adding your classes to an existing project then it may cause a conflict with an existing view id. The ids need to be enough to uniquely identify the view within your project. A better name is something like "statistics_linechart" (notice all in lowercase letters as well) You will also need to debug and set a breakpoints to determine whether your `LineChart` is being found correctly